# Java selenium access object from js executed script in return

Tags: java, selenium

My question is very simple, for example I have this code:

```
Object objReturn = js.executeScript("""
  return { length: 1, textContent: 'text' };
""");
```

I printed it and it showed {length=1, textContent='text'}. But my problem is I need to access it. Doing `objReturn.length or objReturn.textContent` won't work.

Comment: `return { length: 1, textContent: 'text' };` is an illegal js statement, so could you tell us your real purpose?

Comment: how is that illegal statement?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about Java? Those triple-quotes `"""` look more like a python syntax..

Answer (score 1):

In Java any value (except of primitive types) has it class that defines what you can do and what you cannot do. Despite any class is derived from `Object` (so that polymorphism implementation allows you to refer to any object with a reference of `Object` type), you can use only that interface that the reference class exposes.

So in your case you use the reference of type `Object` that does not obviously have fields like `length` or `textContent`. However if you run your code in debug, you will see that your JS execution statement returns a `Map`. So in your particular case the solution would be:

```java
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Map result = (Map) executor.executeScript("return { length: 1, textContent: 'text' };");
System.out.println(result.get("length"));
System.out.println(result.get("textContent"));
```